# OpenLayers - remove all layers of map apart from base map layer?

Tags: openlayers, layers, basemap

What i need is to delete all layers from the map without removing the base one `(in my case OSM)`

Here is some code

```
    new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({ source: new OSM() }) // <== the one i dont want to be removed
      ],
      controls: [
        new Zoom({ zoomInLabel: '', zoomOutLabel: '' })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: proj.fromLonLat([center.lon, center.lat]),
        zoom
      }),
      target: div
    });
```

I can iterate over them with a `forEach` and applying `map.removeLayer(layer);` but i can't distinguish it with the other layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your basemap layer to a variable, and in the map layers, include the layer by variable rather than creating in in-place:

```
basemap = new TileLayer({ source: new OSM() })

new Map({
  layers: [ basemap ],
  controls: [
    new Zoom({ zoomInLabel: '', zoomOutLabel: '' })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: proj.fromLonLat([center.lon, center.lat]),
    zoom
  }),
  target: div
});
```

Then in your `forEach`, you can do an `if` to conditionally delete only the layers that are not equal to the `basemap` variable.

Alternatively, when removing all other layers you could avoid the `forEach` loop by simply re-defining the map's layers to be:  `[ basemap ]`